# Sull'uso e significato del termine "distinguo" come sinonimo di "distinzione"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, synonym

Su questo [articolo di Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2020/04/28/covid-19-l-europa-verso-la-fase-2-ecco-le-date) mi sono imbattuta nella frase seguente (grassetto mio):

> La Francia che aveva già sbandierato la data dell'11 maggio, fa un **distinguo**, se gli indicatori non rispettano le aspettative non si farà nessuna apertura e questo vuol dire che i contagi devono mantenersi tra i 1000 e i 3000, in base a queste cifre i dipartimenti saranno divisi in zone verdi e rosse e questo fino al 2 giugno.

Quando ho letto "un distinguo" (termine che non conoscevo), ho subito pensato: perché si usa "un distinguo" invece di "una distinzione"?

Ricercando alla [voce "distinguo" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/distinguo/), ho trovato:

> è passata poi nell’uso corrente a indicare, con sfumatura per lo più iron. e peggiorativa, la distinzione stessa: *cominciò a sollevare tutta una serie di distinguo*; *con i suoi d. bloccò ogni discussione*.

Tuttavia, non mi sembra che l'intenzione del testo di Euronews sia quella di dare una sfumatura ironica o peggiorativa.

Ho ricercato l'espressione "fa un distinguo" su Google e ne ho trovato parecchie occorrenze, ma non saprei dire quali sono le sfumature del termine in ogni testo. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: è comune usare il vocabolo "distinguo" semplicemente come un sinonimo di "distinzione" (senza aggiungere nessuna sfumatura particolare)? Con "comune" intendo che si tratta di  un uso del termine che si può trovare in altri testi o discorsi e non è invece un'invenzione dell'autore della frase o un vocabolo usato male.

Comment: Forse bisogna definire cosa si intende per “uso comune”. Comunque l’espressione “fare un distinguo” è usata, forse è un po’ formale, ma di facile comprensione.

Comment: “Distinzione” è un termine neutro, “distinguo” e un particolare tipo di distinzione: *”per estensione distinzione sottile e precisa; spesso spreg., distinzione cavillosa, argomentazione pedante: con tutti i suoi distinguo non ci fa mai concludere nulla.*” De Mauro

Comment: Nel caso dell’uso di Euronews, “distinguo” è usato col significato di   “distinzione precisa” (vedi de Mauro) senza connotazioni di spregevolezza o ironia.

Comment: È curioso come Ngram mostri un uso in costante aumento di “fare un/dei distinguo” dagli anni ‘60/‘70. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fare+un+distinguo%2C+fare+dei+distinguo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfare%20un%20distinguo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfare%20dei%20distinguo%3B%2Cc0

Comment: “*La parola distinzione va bene, è un sinonimo sempre utilizzabile, e sicuramente è più usata. Distinguo è più formale ed effettivamente a volte è più pignola, come dice il dizionario.

Quando si fa un distinguo molto spesso si va a cercare un motivo molto particolare per fare una distinzione, per non considerare due cose, o due persone,  alla stessa stregua, nello stesso modo.*” https://italianosemplicemente.com/2019/11/26/n-142-fare-un-distinguo-2-minuti-con-italiano-semplicemente/

Comment: @Hachi:  Quindi, quando "distinguo" non ha una sfumatura ironica o peggiorativa, significa "distinzione sottile e precisa"? E questo sarebbe il senso del termine nell'articolo di Euronews?

Comment: Si, come tutti i dizionari precisano, l’uso è fatto prevalentemente in senso ironico o spregevole, ma non sempre. L’idea è di fare delle distinzioni cavillose, di apparente poca importanza. Nell’articolo, le aperture annunciate dalla Francia hanno dei distinguo, ossia dei casi precisi  in cui le aperture non si faranno. Il link di cui sopra mi sembra spieghi bene anche con esempi l’uso dell’espressione.

Comment: @Hachi:  Cioè, una distinzione basata sui valori di un parametro (se il parametro prendi valori in tale intervallo, si fa A; se il parametro prendi valori in tale altro intervallo, si fa B; ...) è meglio definita con il termine "distinguo"?

Comment: Veramente quello che si spiega nel sito web che hai linkato non lo capisco del tutto bene. Prima afferma "il dizionario dice che un **distinguo** è una **distinzione**, una **precisazione**, per lo più **pedante** e **pignolesca**, insomma, un **cavillo**", ma poi fa esempi come "una mamma non fa distinguo tra i propri figli", che non capisco cosa avrebbe a che vedere con "cavilli", "pignoleria", "pedanteria" o "distinzione sottile e precisa".

Comment: Significa che una mamma non fa nessun tipo di distinzione, di nessun genere,  tra i propri figli.

Comment: Sì, questo lo capisco, @Hachi: quello che non mi è del tutto chiaro è che questo uso corrisponda alla definizione di "distinguo": sembra si usi "distinguo" semplicemente come equivalente di "distinzione" (che è quello che chiedo nella domanda).

Comment: ***Un distinguo è una distinzione***, un tipo di distinzione che generalmente ha le caratteristiche di cui abbiamo già parlato.

Comment: @Hachi grazie, ho capito anche io!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il Sabatini-Coletti propone

> Nel linguaggio comune, distinzione che annuncia un'obiezione: *fare un distinguo*; anche, in senso spregiativo, distinzione cavillosa e pedante: *non fare troppi distinguo*.

Il dizionario Hoepli invece

> 1 FILOS Nella filosofia scolastica, formula che introduceva l'analisi di un'argomentazione volta a stabilire una distinzione
>
> 2 estens. Distinzione sottile o artificiosa: *solleva continuamente acuti distinguo*

Qui c'è l'origine del termine, che anche il Treccani conferma. Il De Mauro ha il significato 1 come nel dizionario Hoepli e anche

> 2. CO estens., distinzione sottile e precisa; spesso spregiativo, distinzione cavillosa, argomentazione pedante: *con tutti i suoi distinguo non ci fa mai concludere nulla*.

Non c'è molto accordo, o forse sì. Quando sento *distinguo* mi immagino qualcuno che si alza e obietta dicendo “Sì, va bene, ma…” e la definizione del Sabatini-Coletti mi sostiene.

Nel caso in esame non vedo senso dispregiativo. Discordano dunque con il Treccani che aggiunge un “per lo più” che mi sembra esagerato: “spesso” sarebbe meglio e le frasi portate come esempi hanno in effetti una connotazione spregiativa (*troppi* oppure *non ci fa concludere nulla*). In *acuti distinguo* il senso spregiativo sicuramente manca, anzi!

L'esempio *una mamma non fa distinguo tra i propri figli* riportato nei commenti mi suona un po' strano e direi più sempicemente *una mamma non distingue tra i suoi figli* o *non fa distinzioni* (l'uso di *propri* indica linguaggio affettato, quindi non lo prenderei come un esempio probante); con *distinguo* potremmo suggerire che la mamma non fa nemmeno distinzioni sottili, quasi impercettibili. Ma è cercare il pelo nell'uovo.

Comment: Nella frase che appare nella domanda dovrei percepire qualche senso o sfumatura di obiezione da parte di qualcuno? O semplicemente si sta usando "distinguo" per "distinzione"?

Comment: E poi deduco che si tratta di un vocabolo di uso più o meno comune, anche se io non l'avevo incontrato prima (e non so se abbia qualcosa a che vedere l'Ngram che ha mostrato Hachi nel suo commento). È così?

Comment: @Charo Non è molto comune, ma diffuso. Nell'articolo penso si voglia sottolineare che la Francia fa una distinzione *particolare*.

Comment: Quindi, il senso sarebbe più quello di "distinzione sottile e precisa" che riporta il De Mauro? (anche se forse non è tanto "sottile", ma va be').

Answer (score 0):

Io credo che in molti casi *distinguo* sia usato per intendere una distinzione con valore critico e oppositivo a un'affermazione ritenuta troppo generica o troppo estremista. Cioé i *distinguo* sono in realtà critiche supportate/originate da una distinzione o una precisazione, che a volte può essere sottaciuta. Talvolta per distinguo s'intende proprio una precisazione.

Ritengo che la spiegazione del Treccani non sia totalmente fedele all'uso diffuso che si fa del vocabolo perché spesso non si usa il termine con ironia e neppure pignoleria o pedanteria, semplicemente si usa al posto di "critica", una critica motivata da distinzioni ritenute necessarie, oppure una precisazione (e in questo caso il termine è usato in modo più vicino al significato originario).

Comment: Allora, dovrei capire che il giornalista fa una critica alla Francia per il fatto di fare questa distinzione?

Comment: @Charo no, il giornalista riporta parole della Francia che critica  sé stessa e cambia idea. Oppure (sempre la Francia) semplicemente precisa meglio qualche cosa detto in precedenza, i *distinguo* possono anche solo essere precisazioni. Nella frase leggo che è la Francia che fa un distinguo.

Comment: Allora, la persona o l'entità che "fa distinguo" è quella che fa la critica? Non riesco a capirlo del tutto bene.

Comment: Dovrei anche capire che l'esempio di quel sito web, cioè, "una mamma non fa distinguo tra i propri figli", ha implicito che possono esistere mamme che fanno distinzioni tra i figli e, allo stesso tempo, criticare i propri figli? (cioè, "il distinguo" è allo stesso tempo una distinzione e una critica da parte della mamma?).

Comment: @charo: in fondo, fare *distinguo* vuol dire evidenziare casi particolari, trattare qualcuno diversamente da altri, oppure precisare. Chi fa "distinguo" solitamente critica o approfondisce. Dire che una mamma non fa distinguo significa portare un esempio naturale (la mamma ama *tutti* i propri figli) perché non si pensa che esistano mamme per le quali i propri figli non sono tutti uguali.